# Google spreadsheet multiple auto-sorting

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, sorting

In a Google Spreadsheet I have different group of cells to auto-sort ascending i.e.

- table range `a3:c16 columntosortby = 2`
- table range `d18:f31
  columntosortby = 5`
- table range `g33:i46 columntosortby = 8`

etc.

By using the following code I'm able to auto-sort the first group:

```
/**
* Automaticamente ordina arrivi gruppo A 
*/

function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 2;
  var tableRange = "a3:c16"; // Celle da ordinare.

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

If I replicate one script for each of others groups only the last script remains active. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution by creating three different scripts:

1. auto-sorting table range a3:c16 columntosortby = 2 ;
2. auto-sorting table range a3:c16 columntosortby = 2 and auto-sorting table range d18:f31 columntosortby = 5;
3. auto-sorting table range a3:c16 columntosortby = 2 + auto-sorting table range d18:f31 columntosortby = 5 + table range g33:i46 columntosortby = 8

Doesn't seems very elegant to me but it functions.